# Error while installing GitLab Runner into the GitLab Project

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szaBC.png)

`Operation failed. Check pod logs for install-runner for more details.`

I am getting this error while trying to install GitLab runner.
What I have done so far

- successfully installed Kubernetes cluster
- created a demo project in Gitlab
- provided details to GitLab for Kubernetes cluster

**Then while trying to installing runner it shows failure.**
What am I missing here? [please check the attached image]

Answer (score 1):

I had was facing the same issue, In my case it was because i had not set `RBAC-enabled cluster` to true. I deleted the intergration and checked `RBAC-enabled cluster` when i re-integrated and it worked.

Runner logs:

```
kubectl logs install-runner -n  gitlab-managed-apps

Error: query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-managed-apps:default" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "gitlab-managed-apps"
```

Reference:

[gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cluster-integration/cluster-applications/-/issues/34)

Answer (score 1):

Warning, with GitLab 13.11 (April 2021):

> ### [One-click GitLab Managed Apps will be removed in GitLab 14.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/04/22/gitlab-13-11-released/#one-click-gitlab-managed-apps-will-be-removed-in-gitlab-14.0)
>
> We are deprecating one-click install of GitLab Managed Apps.
>
> Although they made it very easy to get started with deploying to Kubernetes from GitLab, the overarching community feedback was that they were not flexible or customizable enough for real-world Kubernetes applications.
>
> Instead, our future direction will focus on [installing apps on Kubernetes via GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/applications.html#install-using-gitlab-cicd-alpha) in order to provide a better balance between ease-of-use and expansive customization.
>
> We plan to remove one-click Managed Apps completely in GitLab version 14.0.
> This will not affect how existing managed applications run inside your cluster, however, you’ll no longer have the ability to modify those applications via the GitLab UI.
>
> We recommend cluster administrators plan to migrate any existing managed applications by reinstalling them either manually or via CI/CD. Migration instructions will be available in our documentation later.
>
> For users of alerts on managed Prometheus, in GitLab version 14.0, we will also remove the ability to setup/modify alerts from the GitLab UI. This change is necessary because the existing solution will no longer function once managed Prometheus is removed.

Deprecation date: May 22, 2021

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I had some issues on the TLS security level.